# How to split a string by signs positioned outside of curly braces in python?

Tags: python

I'm writting a python script to get the linearisation of `cos^n`.
In order to format in LaTeX, I'd like to split the obtained expression with respect to delimiters.

For instance I've

```
expr = \frac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{32}e^{3\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{16}e^{\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{16}e^{-\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{32} e^{-3\jmath\theta} + \frac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta}
```

and I'd want to group by `±\frac{.}{.} e^{.}`

I've tried `re.split('([\+-])', expr)` but obviously it also splits within the braces...

Since it's the very first time I use regex, how can I get what I want?

Comment: Doesn't look like you need regex, did you try to: `expr.split(' + ')` ?

Comment: Is there a backslash missing?

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/eu4Juy/1 ?

Comment: @alfasin, actually it's the simpliest way, but it removes the signs.

Comment: @KlausD. backslash added ;)
Your solution works fine.

However, what do I've to change if there are spaces (or not!) between \frac{}{} and exp?

Comment: @NBur: you can add `' ?'` for "1 space or not". See my answer.

Comment: @KlausD. can you turn your comment in an answer so that I can accept it?
The `' ?'` addition by Eric Duminil works fine.

Comment: @NBur it's not a hard problem to add it back ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are multiple regexen you could use.

First you should take care with `'\'` when defining the string:

```
>>> '\f'
'\x0c'
>>> '\\f'
'\\f'
>>> print('\f')


>>> print('\\f')
\f
```

So you can define `text` this way:

```
>>> text = "expr = \\frac{1}{32}e^{-5\\jmath\\theta} + \\frac{5}{32}e^{3\\jmath\\theta} + \\frac{5}{16}e^{\\jmath\\theta} + \\frac{5}{16}e^{-\\jmath\\theta} + \\frac{5}{32} e^{-3\\jmath\\theta} + \\frac{1}{32}e^{-5\\jmath\\theta}"
```

You need `re` module for regex:

```
>>> import re
```

You could simply look for everything inside `{}`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', text)
['{1}', '{32}', '{-5\\jmath\\theta}', '{5}', '{32}', '{3\\jmath\\theta}', '{5}', '{16}', '{\\jmath\\theta}', '{5}', '{16}', '{-\\jmath\\theta}', '{5}', '{32}', '{-3\\jmath\\theta}', '{1}', '{32}', '{-5\\jmath\\theta}']
```

If you don't want the `{}`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\{).*?(?=\})', text)
['1', '32', '-5\\jmath\\theta', '5', '32', '3\\jmath\\theta', '5', '16', '\\jmath\\theta', '5', '16', '-\\jmath\\theta', '5', '32', '-3\\jmath\\theta', '1', '32', '-5\\jmath\\theta']
```

If you want a list of tuples with 3 elements: the expressions inside `±\frac{.}{.} e^{.}`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\\frac\{(.*?)}{(.*?)} ?e\^{(.*?)}', text)
[('1', '32', '-5\\jmath\\theta'), ('5', '32', '3\\jmath\\theta'), ('5', '16', '\\jmath\\theta'), ('5', '16', '-\\jmath\\theta'), ('5', '32', '-3\\jmath\\theta'), ('1', '32', '-5\\jmath\\theta')]
```

If you want the whole expressions, possibly starting with a `+` or a `-`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[\+\-]? ?\\frac\{.*?}{.*?} ?e\^{.*?}', text)
[' \\frac{1}{32}e^{-5\\jmath\\theta}', '+ \\frac{5}{32}e^{3\\jmath\\theta}', '+ \\frac{5}{16}e^{\\jmath\\theta}', '+ \\frac{5}{16}e^{-\\jmath\\theta}', '+ \\frac{5}{32} e^{-3\\jmath\\theta}', '+ \\frac{1}{32}e^{-5\\jmath\\theta}']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split on `+`

```
expr = '\frac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{32}e^{3\jmath\theta} + 
\frac{5}{16}e^{\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{16}e^{-\jmath\theta} + \frac{5}{32} 
e^{-3\jmath\theta} + \frac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta}'

com = expr.split(' + ')
print(com)
```

Output:

> ['\x0crac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta}', '\x0crac{5}{32}e^{3\jmath\theta}', '\x0crac{5}{16}e^{\jmath\theta}', '\x0crac{5}{16}e^{-\jmath\theta}', '\x0crac{5}{32} e^{-3\jmath\theta}', '\x0crac{1}{32}e^{-5\jmath\theta}']

**<kbd>[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/RaoPKe)</kbd>**

Comment: Simplest way, but it removes the sign in front of `\frac`.
In addition, sometimes there is a - sign (in case of `sin` linearisation)

Comment: Also, you should take care when defining `expr`. `\f` is converted to `\x0c`.

Comment: Sure! But strings are automatically generated with sympy.latex